# Word error: "SELECT * FROM 'Sheet1$'"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

When I open some word documents I get this error:

> Opening this document will run the following SQL command: "SELECT *
>   FROM 'Sheet1$'"

Is there any way to see where this procedure is stored or what items it populates?

Maybe someone just copied some data from an Excel file and pasted it in a Word document.
I want to see if it does something, so I can be sure that I can delete it.

PS: in View->Marcos there is no recorded macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the File tab of the ribbon.

Make sure that Info is selected at the left side of the screen.

At the bottom-right side of the screen, under the Related Documents category, click Edit Links to Files. (If this option is not available, it means that Word doesn't think there are any links in the current document.) Word displays the Links dialog box. (See Below)

[image]

Select the link you want to break.
Click on Break Link. You are asked to confirm your action.
Click on OK.